# QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem similars for Wt

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene, wt

Are there QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsItem ... similars for Wt ?

I need to draw several graphic items (an arbitrary scene) and be able to interact with items (basically mouse event response for change item's visual aspects). How can I achieve this in Wt?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple: at the moment, Wt doesn't implement such functionality. You need to use the [painting system](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/group__painting.html) and manage your items in your own code.

Since a lot of your functionality needs to reside on the client, to keep the interaction smooth, you'd be writing both C++ and Javascript, and you'll need to understand the internals of Wt to some degree.

Wt is not "the entire Qt for the web": at the moment it is an amalgamation of selected functionality from Qt 1, Qt 2 and Qt 3, but it's about where early Qt 2 was when it comes to core functionality.